# Installing 64 bit Python on ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcpy, installation, 64bit, 32bit

I am trying to have `Python 64-bit` with ArcGIS so that I can use my entire RAM when doing data analysis. Apparently ArcGIS 10.2.2 Desktop comes just with 'Python 32-bit'.

Should I install a fresh `Python 64-bit` and import `arcpy` from there?

Is that going to work?

I need to use `arcpy` and `scipy` libraries for my data analysis and I need to call both of these libraries in my Python code.

Is there a better way to run 'Python 64-bit' with ArcGIS?

Comment: 64-bit Background Geoprocessing installs a 64-bit version of Python 2.7.2, NumPy and Matplotlib if they are not already installed. By default they will be installed to C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.1 (note the x64 in the path), an additional install from the 32-bit Python (C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1) that Desktop and Engine install and use.

Comment: @Mapperz, can you post this as an answer?

Comment: set PYTHONPATH=%PYTHONPATH%;C:\My_python_lib https://docs.python.org/3.3/using/windows.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**64-bit Background Geoprocessing with ArcGIS**

> 64-bit Background Geoprocessing installs a 64-bit version of Python
>   2.7.2, NumPy and Matplotlib if they are not already installed. By default they will be installed to C:\Python27\ArcGISx6410.1 (note the
>   x64 in the path), an additional install from the 32-bit Python
>   (C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.1) that Desktop and Engine install and use

source:
http://blogs.esri.com/esri/arcgis/2012/11/12/python-scripting-with-64-bit-processing/

Comment: My Python directory currently is `C:\Python27\ArcGIS 10.2`. How can I install 64-bit background Geoprocessing on top of Python 32-bit that I already have?

Comment: @bikhaab You don't install it "on top." You install a separate Python interpreter in a separate location (via the 64 bit background processing installer) and use that.

Comment: I'm trying to download and install it from [this link](http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/patches-servicepacks/view/productid/153/metaid/2105?keepThis=true&TB_iframe=true&height=500&width=850&caption=Esri+Support+-+New+Service+Packs). Though, I get an error regarding redistributing C++ 2010 while installing it. Is that the right file for ArcGIS 10.2.2?

Comment: at the bottom ArcGIS-1022-BGDT-SRC-Patch.msp http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/patches-servicepacks/view/productid/67/metaid/2098

Comment: After downloading and trying to install, I get this error: 

`The upgrade patch cannot be installed by the Windows Installer service because the program to be upgraded is missing, or the upgrade patch may upgrade a different version of the program`

I'm pretty sure that I have `ArcGIS 10.2.2` installed!! Any thoughts on that?

Comment: I have the same problem with installing the patch downloaded from @Mapperz's link. what is the solution?