# ArcPy on 64 bit Windows

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, 64bit

I can't import arcpy into 64 bit Python. It works just fine in the python install from arcGIS, though. When I try to import it elsewhere, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\__init__.py", line 21, in <module>
from arcpy.geoprocessing import gp
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\__init__.py", line 14, in <module>
from _base import *
  File "C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.2\arcpy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 14, in <module>
import arcgisscripting
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

I've been looking for a solution, but what I'm finding seems to be "too bad, doesn't work in 64-bit." Is this the case?

Edit: working with ArcGIS 10.2.2, Python 2.7.8

Edit: I believe the problem is that I only have the trial version of ArcMap, which apparently doesn't support the 64-bit background geoprocessing installation

Comment: The 32-bit ArcPy doesn't work with 64-bit Python, but the 64-bit geoprocessing package does.  Have you downloaded and installed the right product?

Comment: A search on "64-bit python arcgis" turned up http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109816/64-bit-python-on-arcgis-10-2-2-for-desktop

Comment: I downloaded it, but trying to install I get: `The upgrade patch cannot be installed by the Windows Installer service because the program to be upgraded is missing, or the upgrade patch may upgrade a different version of the program`

Comment: Please update the question with the *exact* ArcGIS Desktop version, the *exact* ArcGIS Server version (if present), the *exact* 64-bit Python version, and the *exact* 64-bit background geoprocessing version.

Comment: My ArcGIS Desktop version is 10.2.2; my Python version is 2.7.8; I can't find any info on the background geoprocessing