# problem with adding 64-bit background geoprocessing to ArcGIS 10.2.2

Tags: python, arcpy, arcgis-10.2, geoprocessing

My code written in python language using Arcpy works perfectly with small to average size datasets; however, with a big dataset, the script stops in the middle of execution which most likely is due to lack of memory. the solution I found is to employe the 64-bit background geoprocessing so that the whole RAM could be used during the running time. the problem is that my ArcGIS 10.2.2 is installed by the technical staff in our department and the 64 bit BG geoprocessing is not set up.
According to the comments [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/109816/64-bit-python-on-arcgis-10-2-2-for-desktop) , I downloaded the relevant patch but when I run it, the following error is appearing:

"The upgrade patch cannot be installed by the Windows Installer service because the program to be upgraded is missing, or the upgrade patch may upgrade a different version of the program"

**Update:**
As I checked, the code jumps out as soon as it starts a function which needs to use FeatureToPolygon function.

do you know how to fix this error or any other workaround for installing the 64-bit background geoprocessing in ArcGIS 10.2.2?

Comment: check your installed version use patch finder at the bottom http://support.esri.com/en/downloads/patches-servicepacks/view/productid/160/metaid/2135#updates

Comment: I did and here is the answer: ArcGIS 10.2.2 for Desktop

Comment: do you get the build number? in ArcGIS Help>About Version 10.2.2.3552

Comment: yes, it is 10.2.2.3552

Comment: @Mapperz: it seems that the recommended patch is only the spatial reference consistency patch. Although I need the whole 64-bit BG GP to be installed. How does it fit?

Comment: I *think* BG is more considered a full product than a patch, as such its here: https://my.esri.com/#/organization-profile , not the patches/servicepacks site. Meaning the person who is authorized to download software at your org needs to login and get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per this [question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/81066/arcgis-10-2-installation-for-64-bit-geoprocessing?lq=1) I think you (or your IT staff)

> need to run the autorun.exe application, it will launch the startup
> window (otherwise known as the Quick Start Guide) of the 10.2
> installation for Desktop.

From here you can install the 64-bit BGP. I realize that this refers to 10.2 not 10.2.2 but I think it is the same process.

[image]

Just a side note: My ArcGIS desktop was also installed by my departments IT section, I recently had to go through IT to install this, the quick start application was not stored locally on my machine it was on the ITs network drive as esri.exe I had to get the location from IT.